# powershell regex options for making a bracket optional

Tags: powershell

I am actually new to powershell regular expression. I need the regular expression to replace the first line of a Create procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Airplane_RBMId
 (
 @IN_AirplaneID INT,
 @IN_RegionBusinessModelID INT
 )
 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

Here there can be two condition where dbo and procedure name can be with or without bracket. So need to make the bracket optional

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Airplane_RBMId
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Airplane_RBMId]
```

The powershell regex i made is working fine with bracket.

```
$Temp = $element -ireplace "\s*CREATE\s*PROCEDURE\s*\[dbo\]\.\[([^\]]+)\]","$CreateBlock"
```

Comment: `?` makes the previous token optional e.g. `\[?`

Answer (score 0):

```
$element -replace '\s*CREATE\s*PROCEDURE\s*(\[dbo]|dbo)\.\[{0,1}(\S+)]{0,1}',$CreateBlock
```

- `(\[dbo]|dbo)` matches either `[dbo]` or `dbo`
- `\[{0,1}` matches 0 or 1 `[` bracket.
- `(\S+)` matches one or more not-whitespaces as the procedure name.
- `]{0,1}` matches 0 or 1 `]` bracket.